# Snippet code to change currency values?

Tags: android

I'm making an App based on *money*, and one feature (not of the **main** ones) needs to **convert** your **amount** of **money** in any **currency** (or at least into the most important ones) you need.
So if I had ***50 Euros***, and I select **Pounds** in the `Spinner`, the value should change from **Euros** to **Pounds**, etc.

Is there a *code* or a *shortcut* to implement this **operation**?
Otherwise, how may I `code` a `method` to do just this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly trivial to implement. Currency values fluctuate frequently enough that to be reasonably accurate you will not be able to just hard code values. You will need to send a request to some kind of currency tracking service's API, like [this one at appspot.](https://currency-api.appspot.com/) This will typically result in some kind of JSON package that you will have to parse.

When to do this exchange depends on your application. If you are doing something where up to the minute accuracy is very important, like a trading app, you would have to make the call when the user requests the information. Otherwise you could call something like [openexchangerates.org](http://openexchangerates.org/) that returns a single json with a very large set of currency values when the user opens your app, and cache those values until needed. That way you can more gracefully handle things like not being connected to the network, but the downside is you will not necessarily be as accurate.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking exactly at the 1st point: to get the values from another App trough its APIs, I'll try to read how to get and parse 'em now. I need to be extremely precise. Thanks, if you have any websites where to study the APIs I'd thank you again! Bye

Comment: I mean, just how do I get that in Java? It's Android here, how should I connect to that website's API? @TBridges42

Comment: Consuming a website API is, I think, a pretty broad subject for an SO answer. Android provides web services through the HttpURLConnection class (remember to declare INTERNET permissions in your manifest), but many people prefer to use an established framework like Spring.

Comment: I'm sure it is! But I'm new to Android, was just wondering how :) Then I should use the HttpURLConnection class, after have declared INTERNET permissions in the manifest.. Thanks I'll make some searches on how to do that xD @TBridges42